Probability of Seeded Players in Same Group During Badminton Tournament
Question:
There are 3 seeded players among the top 12 badminton singles players.
If these 12 people are randomly divided into 3 groups with 4 people each, what's the probability that the 3 seeded players end up in the same group?

Is the following approach correct? Why?
By the given conditions, dividing 12 people into 3 groups (each group has 4 people) in different grouping methods has $\frac{C_{12}^{4}C_{8}^{4}C_{4}^{4}}{A_{3}^{3}}$ kinds. The method of having 3 seeded players in the same group has $\frac{C_{9}^{1}C_{8}^{4}C_{4}^{4}}{A_{2}^{2}}$ kinds (easy to miss: evenly divide the problem by the full permutation number of the evenly divided number). Therefore, the probability that 3 seeded players are well distributed in the same group is $\frac{3}{55}$.

Looks good.  For another approach:  Place $A$ in whatever group.  $B$ is in the same group with probability $\frac 3{11}$ and then $C$ is also in the same group with probability $\frac 2{10}=\frac 15$.  And the product is $\frac 3{55}$.

$\frac3{55}$ is correct.
It can be calculated more easily with something like

with the first seeded player put in any of the twelve slots,
then the conditional probability the second seeded player is put in any of the three remaining slots in the first seeded player's group is $\frac3{11}$,
and the conditional probability the third seeded player is put in either of the two remaining slots in the first and second seeded players' group is $\frac2{10}$,

The product of these is $\frac{3}{55}$.

Alternative approach:
Whichever group the first seeded player goes into, there will be $~3~$ positions remaining, in that group.  There will also be $~11~$ total positions remaining.
Therefore, the probability is
$$\frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{11}{2}}.$$
